# How to properly POST FormData from Svelte to FastAPI?

Tags: svelte, fastapi, pydantic

I am new to Svelte and trying to use FastAPI as the backend and Svelte as the frontend. I am trying to upload the image and `POST` it to backend FastAPI validated by pydantic. I have 2 questions:

1. What is the correct way to write `form` in Svelte? I made 2 versions, but I am confused about the correct way to write in Svelte, or are the 2 processes the same?

```html
<form class="py-2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="imagefileinput" id="imagefile" class="rounded-lg w-full text-gray-700 border-2 border-gray-700 my-2 text-2xl" required accept="image/jpeg"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="w-full ease-in-out duration-300 text-gray-700 hover:text-white text-2xl border-2 border-gray-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700"/>
</form>
```

and

```html
<form class="py-2" on:submit|preventDefault={post_form}>
      <input type="file" name="imagefileinput" id="imagefile" class="rounded-lg w-full text-gray-700 border-2 border-gray-700 my-2 text-2xl" required accept="image/jpeg" bind:files={fileVar}/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="w-full ease-in-out duration-300 text-gray-700 hover:text-white text-2xl border-2 border-gray-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700"/>
</form>
```

2. Why I am getting the `405 Method Not Allowed` when `POST`ing the `FormData`?

```html
<script lang="js">
  let fileVar;
  let fileName;
  async function post_form(){
    let dataArray = new FormData();
    dataArray.append("imagefileinput", fileVar[0], fileName);
    fetch("/post", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      body: dataArray
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
</script>

<main>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 mx-12 mt-3 rounded-md p-3 text-black">
    <span class="text-3xl">Image</span>
    <form class="py-2" on:submit|preventDefault={post_form}>
      <input type="file" name="imagefileinput" id="imagefile" class="rounded-lg w-full text-gray-700 border-2 border-gray-700 my-2 text-2xl" required accept="image/jpeg" bind:files={fileVar}/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="w-full ease-in-out duration-300 text-gray-700 hover:text-white text-2xl border-2 border-gray-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>


<style>

</style>
```

In backend

```py
routes = [
    Mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="front/dist", html=True),
          name="templates")
]

middleware = [
    Middleware(CORSMiddleware,
               allow_origins=['*'],
               allow_credentials=True,
               allow_methods=["*"],
               allow_headers=["*"])
]

app = FastAPI(routes=routes, middleware=middleware)

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse, name='homepage')
async def get_data(request: Request):
    """GET Request
    """
    return RedirectResponse(url="/")


@app.post('/post', response_model=FormData, name='homepage_post')
async def post_data(request: Request, file: FormData = Depends(FormData.as_form)):
    print(file.file)
    return file.file.filename
```

Also tried with `@app.get()` same error.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Form()` obj instead of `FormData()`:

```py
from fastapi import Form

@app.post('/post', response_model=FormData, name='homepage_post')
async def post_data(request: Request, file: FormData = Form():
    print(file.file)
    return file.file.filename
```

Comment: Same error. `405`